# ISCSI iscsi_trgt sess_param_check(55) default_retain_time is out of range

Tags: iscsi

Clustered ISCSI target has been installed based on Ubuntu Server 12.04 amd64.
Target is working, but I have few kernel messages, when heartbeat
starts iscsi service.

```
Sep  5 08:47:58 cluster01 kernel: [  417.004662] iscsi_trgt: sess_param_check(55) default_retain_time: 20 is out of range (0 0)
Sep  5 08:47:58 cluster01 kernel: [  417.028006] iscsi_trgt: sess_param_check(54) max_outstanding_r2t: 8 is out of range (1 1)
```

I did'nt find any descrition of these messages over entireGoogle.

Here is my target definition in ietd.conf:

```
Target iqn.2012-08.hu.mod:storage.redmine
        Lun 0 Path=/dev/drbd6,Type=blockio,ScsiId=mod-redmine,ScsiSN=mod-redmine
        Alias redmine
        MaxConnections         1
        MaxSession              0
        InitialR2T             Yes
        ImmediateData          No
        MaxRecvDataSegmentLength 8192
        MaxXmitDataSegmentLength 8192
        MaxBurstLength         262144
        FirstBurstLength       65536
        DefaultTime2Wait       2
        DefaultTime2Retain     20
        MaxOutstandingR2T      8
        DataPDUInOrder         Yes
        DataSequenceInOrder    Yes
        ErrorRecoveryLevel     0
        HeaderDigest           CRC32C,None
        DataDigest             CRC32C,None
        Wthreads               32
```

Can you please give me any advice, how can I solve this problem?

Thank You & Bet Regards

Istvan

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use GlusterFS 3.2.x On Ubuntu 12.04. It's so easy to manage and use.
 You can read [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/high-availability-storage-with-glusterfs-3.2.x-on-ubuntu-12.04-automatic-file-replication-across-two-storage-servers) for more information how to setup